# Map domain model to legacy database

Tags: hibernate

First of all I need to say that I'm not an expert in Hibernate. I only used the basics of it in other projects. But now, I want to use Hibernate on a legacy database scheme but I'm experiencing some difficulties to map tables to a Java domain model:

1) Lots of tables have a primary key (as a String) which are assigned by the user. So they are not generated according some algorithm. They in fact are what Hibernate calls 'natural' keys.
Is there a way to tell Hibernate to accept an ID assigned by the user?

2) The second problem is that lot of tables have some common properties like: valid_from, valid_to, date_created, date_last_modified, user_last_modified & user_created.
These properties are used for auditing (which record was changed by which user) and to disable records when the 'valid_to' date field is in the past. I don't want to expose these fields to the end user because they seem to be 'meta data', but I have to find a way to get these fields updated. Is there a generic solution in Hibernate that I can use to update these fields whenever a record is changed? For information, these fields are also used in 'link tables' which are used to manage many-to-many relationships between 2 tables.

All help is very appreciated!

update:
I will use an AbstractEntity to hold the common properties and use an EventListener to insert/update these fields. The user will be retrieved by something UserContext.getCurrentUser() (the user will be bound to the current thread using ThreadLocal).

The only issue now is how to deal with those 'association' tables... They also contain those common fields and I don't want to create a separate Class to map such association table. In my opinion, Hibernate does a great job to hide such link-table. I there a way to update such link table with an EventListener?

For instance: if table A has a many-to-many relation with class B via link table A_B, is there a way to update A_B whenever a record is inserted/updated on A or B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you use JPA annotations to declare your mapping.

**First problem.** Just do not apply `@GeneratedValue` annotation.

```
public class SomeEntityWithAutogeneratedId {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue // autogeneration
    private Long id;
}

public class SomeEntityWithoutAutogeneratedId {
    @Id
    private String id;
}
```

**Second problem.** You can prepare a base class to simplify mapping of common fields. Then you can use `@PrePersist` to apply correct values for all necessary fields before update:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Column
    private Date dateLastModified;

    @PrePersist
    public void beforePersist() {
        this.dateLastModified = new Date();
    }
}

public class Entity1 extends AbstractEntity {
public class Entity2 extends AbstractEntity {
public class Entity3 extends AbstractEntity {
...
public class EntityN extends AbstractEntity {
```

In general if you want use a legacy database via Hibernate it will be better to review table structures / relations and make appropriate changes before starting write the code. This can save you a lot of time. For example it will be better to:

- replace composite keys with autogenerated unique identifiers (see [this entry from the official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-pojo-identifier) for explanation)
- Remove / replace by hibernate features or java code all triggers or stored procedures. If all your logic is in the application code then it will be easy to use cache features.
- I can't imagine something else right now, but you can have a very long list because SQL database gives you much more power / fetures that can't be easily used via Hibernate